# Clarification on WSO2 ESB in-sequence and main sequence

Tags: wso2-esb

I understand ESB has in-sequence, out sequence and fault sequence, Is in-sequence same as main sequence ?

Also I would like to know if we define receive sequence in a endpoint will it override default behaviour and response is handled by specified received sequence ? Will response handled by default sequence if received sequence is not specified explicitly  ?

Most of the WSO2 ESB examples in internet are based on proxy service, I would like to understand how sequence can be used without proxy service, Can you please introduce me to a such tutorial ?

Comment: In sequence , out sequence and fault sequences are something specific to Proxy Service ? Probably I am missing something to clearly understand this,

Answer (score 1):

Triggering Messages

Messages come into the ESB through the following triggers:

```
A proxy service receives messages that have been sent to a specific endpoint.
A task injects a message into the ESB at a scheduled interval.
A REST API call sends a message to the ESB.
```

When the ESB receives a message, it sends it either to a proxy service or to the Main sequence for handling. The proxy or sequence is configured with message mediation, which controls how the message will be transformed, filtered, forwarded, etc.

To trigger messages in the ESB, see the following topics:

```
Creating APIs
Working with Proxy Services
Working with Tasks
Using REST
```

Source = https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Triggering+Messages

About the Main and Fault Sequences

A mediation configuration holds two special sequences named main and fault. All messages that are not destined for Proxy Services are sent through the main sequence. By default, the main sequence simply sends a message without mediation, so to add message mediation, you add mediators and/or named sequences in the main sequence.

By default, the fault sequence will log the message, the payload, and any error/exception encountered, and the drop mediator stops further processing. You should configure the fault sequence with the correct error handling instead of simply dropping messages. For more information, see Error Handling.

Source = https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Mediation+Sequences#MediationSequences-mainSequence

> Also I would like to know if we define receive sequence in a endpoint will it override default behaviour and response is handled by specified received sequence ? Will response handled by default sequence if received sequence is not specified explicitly ?

Correct , in a proxy though , and the default behaviour is to send to "out sequence"

Comment: Thanks !, I have a question, Any Proxy service will have a target(That can be obtained by accessing the services from ESB admin console), so any request can be send to the specific proxy, I don't understand how to send request not to use any proxy and send to main sequence ? Please show me an example or tutorial explaining this, for some reason I cant get it clearly by just reading the documentation , my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a beginner at this , just know what I know through (a lot of) trial and error ;)

Ok so assuming you have a default offset of  0 , you're ESB instance should have 2 default transports/ports :

> HTTP = 8280
>   HTTPS = 8243

So , any message sent to these ports will reach the main sequence , UNLESS , they are service specific endpoints, so for example , for a soap message with endpoint :

```
http://localhost:8280
```

this will reach the default main sequence , and the following

`https://localhost:8243/services/yourProxyService` ,

will got to the in sequence of the yourProxyService.

Also , in [esb_home]/repository/conf/log4j.properties , set/uncomment the following lines :

```
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=DEBUG
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=DEBUG ,
```

this should show you much more info in the log and make it easier to know which sequence you are in..

feel free to ask me other stuff , cool

Comment: Thanks, I did not know we can send request to ESB without mentioning any targets .

Comment: Please tick as answered then